# Getting different encryption strings between openssl CLI and C codeHello

Tags: c, openssl

I've been playing with openssl and am trying to write a simple program in C for encrypting a string. I'm trying to replicate the following command to encrypt the string "test" and then see the encrypted version using a given key and IV and AES-CBC-128:

```
echo test | openssl enc -e -aes-128-cbc -nosalt -K 5a5a5a5a5a5a5a5a5a5a5a5a5a5a5a5a -iv 00000000000000000000000000000000 | xxd
```

and this returns the encrypted string in hex of

```
a63b e13d 47a5 b94c c1cb 466e 28af 19d8
```

I'm trying to replicate this in C with the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <openssl/aes.h>

int main() {
    AES_KEY aes;
    unsigned char* input_string = "test";
    unsigned char* encrypt_string;
    unsigned int len;
    unsigned char key[] = {0x5A, 0x5A, 0x5A, 0x5A, 0x5A, 0x5A, 0x5A, 0x5A,
                           0x5A, 0x5A, 0x5A, 0x5A, 0x5A, 0x5A, 0x5A, 0x5A};

    unsigned char iv[] = {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
                          0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};

    uint32_t result;
    result = AES_set_encrypt_key(key, 128, &aes);
    if (result < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to set encryption key in AES\n");
        printf("%i", result);
        exit(-1);
    }

    // set the encryption length
    len = 0;
    if ((strlen("test") + 1) % AES_BLOCK_SIZE == 0) {
        len = strlen("test") + 1;
    } else {
        len = ((strlen("test") + 1) / AES_BLOCK_SIZE + 1) * AES_BLOCK_SIZE;
    }

    encrypt_string = (unsigned char*)calloc(len, sizeof(unsigned char));
    AES_cbc_encrypt(input_string, encrypt_string, 128, &aes, iv , AES_ENCRYPT);

    printf("encrypted string = ");
    for (int i=0; i<len; ++i) {
        printf("%02X ", encrypt_string[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

and this returns the encrypted string as

```
encrypted string = C2 5D 07 2D D5 EC DB 94 3B FE 31 9F 51 DE EE 93
```

which doesn't match what I get from the CLI. What am I missing here that causing these not to match?

Comment: Try using `echo -n`.

Comment: `echo test` is appending newline

Comment: `echo -n test | openssl enc -e -aes-128-cbc -nosalt -K 5a5a5a5a5a5a5a5a5a5a5a5a5a5a5a5a -iv 00000000000000000000000000000000 | xxd` is returning `a30f 75f2 51f8 6c4a ab25 0e7f 925a ad12`. Still different

Comment: Commandline (and EVP) uses **PKCS5/7 padding** (by default); your code uses low-level (block oriented) calls without handling padding so it actually encrypts the bytes 74 65 73 74 00 (the string "test") plus 11 bytes of whatever happens to be next in the memory of your process. Try instead `unsigned char input_string[16] = {'t','e','s','t','\n', 11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11}`. And the length passed to `AES_cbc_encrypt` is in bytes -- 16 not 128.

Comment: In fact you actually encrypted the bytes 74 65 73 74 00 65 6E 63 72 79 70 74 65 64 20 73 which is "test" plus its null terminator followed by the characters of "encrypted s" (with no terminator), which is the first oart of the next string literal in source order.